# chartjs show nearest point on hover

Tags: chart.js

I'm currently trying to reproduce the chart you can see on https://discordstatus.com/ for the API Response Time.

However I'm unable to always show the nearest label depending on the mouse position on the X axis. I've tried different configurations for interactions ([Chart.js Interactions](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html#interactions)) but fail to get the desired outcome.

Also it would be nice to show a vertical line dependent on the current active point. As well as always show the tooltip at the top left.

Is this possible with the default chart.js library or do i have to add a plugin or some own modifications?

Here is my current configuration:

```
const data = {
    datasets: [{
        label: 'RTT',
        backgroundColor: '#C00122',
        borderColor: '#C00122',
        borderWidth: 2,
    }]
};

const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        animation: false,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        pasing: false,
        plugins: {
            legend: false
        },
        elements: {
            point: {
                radius: 1
            }
        },
        scales: {
            x: {
                type: 'time',
                time: {
                    unit: 'second',
                    displayFormats: {
                        'second': 'H:mm:ss',
                    }
                },
                ticks: {
                    minRotation: 0,
                    maxRotation: 0,
                    maxTicksLimit: 5
                }
            },
            y: {
                min: 0,
                ticks: {
                    stepSize: 10
                }
            }
        },
        hover: {
            mode: 'index'
        }
    }
};
```

**EDIT:** My datasets are filled dynamically as described here: [Updating Charts](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html)

Comment: Are you looking for `options: { interaction: { mode: 'index' } }`? [Here would be the docs.](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html#modes)

Comment: I guess. The docs sound like this is the config for the behaviour I'm looking for. But it doesn't work. I still have to hover a point perfectly for the tooltip to show. My data is added dynamically maybe this has to do something with it?

Comment: Try `options.interaction.intersect: false`

Comment: That worked! Thanks. Any idea how i can achieve the vertical line and position the label at the top left corner? Feel free to post it as answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I post @Madluca answer in the comment here for helping future readers easy to find answer

This problem can be resolved by

```
options: {
    interaction: {
        intersect: false,
        mode: 'index'
    }
}
```

Here is doc https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html#modes